# Google Console Chrome jQuery extract the name and URL from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to extract all links and text from the HTML source code and add it to a multidimensional array using the google come console

Code snippet -- repeated 10 times

```
<div class="Contentx">
    <a style='text-decoration:none;' href='Tate-Tea.com'>
        <h2>Tate Tea<br>
            <span class='Fis'>Tate-Tea.com</a></span>
        </h2>
        </span>
```

The result would be an array

```
{'Tate-Tea.com','Tate Tea'}
```

I am having a difficulty finding `a style='text-decoration`

So I guess match

Loop around and append to the array ..

```
 Var list = []

 document.querySelectorAll('a[style.textDecoration:none]')
.each(function(){
 var URL = $(this).attr("href");
 var URL_name =  alert($(this).text());
..# append to list 
list.push ({   URL : '', 
URL_name : ''

}}

});
```

`document.querySelector('a[style]').href`
`document.querySelector('a[style]').text`
I can get one of them by using following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find all `a` tag and then manipulate those of that meats this `style.textDecoration == "none"` condition.

Try this one:

```js
        var list = []

        document.querySelectorAll('a')
            .forEach(function (tag) {
                if (tag.style.textDecoration == "none") {
                    var URL = tag.getAttribute("href");
                    var URL_name = alert(tag.text);

                    list.push({
                        URL: URL,
                        URL_name: URL_name
                    })
                }
            });

        console.log(list);
```

```html
 <div class="Contentx">
        <a style='text-decoration:none;' href='Tate-Tea.com'> <h2>Tate Tea<br><span class='Fis'>Tate-Tea.com</a></span></h2> </span>
    </div>
```